# Automatic Resize images in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, collectionview

I used an Image inside collection view(entire cell). Images I'm getting from API. I need to resize width & height of collection view & cell based on image size dynamically. Help me out.

Comment: Use this fucntion `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {}` And on the basis of Image size you can return size of collection Cell.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But based on the image size I need to set collection view height, not a cell. Help me out.

Comment: To set the size of collectionView you can simply do: `var collectionViewHeight = noOfcells*cellHeight` and `collectionViewWidth = cellWidth`